# Mirroring a string of text using Python

Tags: python, string, mirror

I am trying to write code to mirror a string within python. I assumed it was similar to mirroring an image or a sound however I cannot get past the loop. The input and output should both be a string.

```
def mirror(text):
  mirrorPoint=(len(text)/2)
  for i in range(0,mirrorPoint):
    text=text[mirrorPoint]
  return text+''.join(string(text))
print mirror('text')
```

I am not sure if this is right, but it gets caught on the second to last line of text.

If the input was 'abcd' the output should yield 'abba'.

Comment: what is `string(text))`?

Comment: Hint: if you `return` inside a loop, then it won't continue looping.

Comment: string I believe should be reversed however I could not get it to work within python

Comment: typo, return should be on the outside

Comment: Why not just use the `reversed` function?

Comment: I have changed it to reversed, it asks me to define it first which is another issue because I have no idea where to begin for it

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `reversed` was added way back in 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
def mirror(text):
    mirror_point = int(len(text)/2)
    res = text[:mirror_point] # Get Slice of Text
    return res + res[::-1] # Add Slice Plus Reverse of the Slice
print mirror( 'abcd')
```

In you code:

`mirrorPoint = (len(text)/2)` will be a float so when passed to range it will not work as `range` needs an integer.

`''.join(string(text))` , you would use `str(text)` if you were going to cast to a `str` but text is already a string so there is no need to cast.

`text = text[mirrorPoint]` keeps changing the value of `text` so you will get an `index error`, if you wanted to store a string variable outside the loop like `res = ""`, you could then use  `res += text[i]` where `text[i]` is each character you want to add

Using your own code:

```
def mirror(text):
    res = ""
    mirrorPoint = int(len(text)/2)
    for i in range(mirrorPoint):
        res += text[i]
    return text[:mirrorPoint] + res[::-1]
```

To handle uneven length strings we need to add `1` to `mirror_point` if the string is an odd length:

```
def mirror(text):
    mirror_point = int(len(text) / 2)
    if mirror_point % 2 == 0:
        res = text[:mirror_point]
    else:
        res = text[:mirror_point+1]
    return res + res[::-1]
```

Comment: You're initial slice should go up to `mirrorPoint + 1` or you will curt out the middle letter of odd length strings - "tweet" should return "tweewt" i think.

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, for future reference it does not need a loop?

Comment: @ddbg, I am just editing, there are a few issues with your own code I will explain

Comment: I think will is right, however using `mirrorPoint + 1` adds a letter within the output making it longer than it should be

Comment: @ddbg it can be done like this: `res = text[:mirrorPoint+len(text)%2]` and then `return text[:mirrorPoint] + res[::-1]`

Comment: which means you can reduce `mirror(text)` to a single line (if you hate clarity): `def mirror(text): return text[:int((len(text)+1)/2)] + text[:int(len(text)/2)][::-1]` :-/

Answer (score 1):

The following reverses any array.

```
any_string[::-1]
```

So using this, the following will get you the middle point of string, get the first half of the string and then concatenate that with the same half of the string reversed.

```
my_string       = "hello"
middle_point    = int(len(my_string/2)) 
mirror_string   = my_string[0:middle_point]+my_string[0:middle_point][::-1]
```

Comment: From the question, they seem to mean mirror the string about it's middle character, from `mirror("abcd")` giving `"abba"`